# Publishing and changes in workbook for tableau online

Tags: tableau-api

I am working on an internal reporting dashboard project . There are majorly 3 roles/level to internal reporting dashboard like higher management, project management etc.
And the breakdown of information for every role/level is different as compare to other roles.

For internal reporting dashboard we have to create a database ( lets say D - SQL SERVER) whose data will be coming from 3 databases ( Lets say A,B,C) after integrating them.

For now as per my research, we can directly link database D using Tableau Live Connection in Tableau Desktop ( Professional ed) and use it to create a dashboard.
To host that workbook for users, I can use Tableau Online  for publishing and to make data visible according to the roles I can use filters to restrict the data.

Now my questions are:
1. Will this workflow will be right ? Am I missing any step or process that I would need to cater.
2. How will the changes reflect in the dashboard once it is published ? Lets say if I have to add any filter/ parameter in the dashboard. Do I need to make the changes on the workbook using Tableau Desktop and automatically changes will be reflected ?
or do I have to host it again on Tableau Online ? Please educate me on this  too.

Thanks for assistance  I have attached a purposed workflow image too.

Regards,

Manail Pasha

[WORKFLOW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UJuI.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your system is not a transactional database, I would avoid a live database connection.  I would recommend a data extract that combines data blending techniques to create a data extract a.k.a .tde file.

I would publish a dashboard with user filters that enable row-level security via filters and ensure users could only see certain data.

Here is a diagram that I would follow if I were you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To add filter/ parameter either you can do it from the desktop and publish it to Tableau online or login to online and add the filter/ parameter from the edit mode and Save it, it will get reflected if you do anyone of the above mentioned method.

If your data is frequently changing, i would recommend to go on with Live Connection, Extract refresh can be done on incremental, but the appropriate fields needs to chosen to do it( you should also consider, how to handle negated entries ). It all up-to you to decide to go on with Extract or Live